I accidentally clicked an extension in Chrome on my Android. How to remove it?
I accidentally clicked on "Add to Desktop" on an extension and now it shows "Added to Desktop" on my Android.



But I can't find extensions in Chrome to remove it. It happens with one of my Google accounts only. When I log in with another Google account and then visit the same extension site, it does not show "Added to Desktop". But when I log in with that Google account which was logged in when I accidentally installed the extension, it always shows "Added to Desktop".
Now how do I remove it?

What happens if you remove that extension from desktop? Chrome on Android doesn't have extensions, so it's likely telling you that you installed this extension on your laptop /PC - not that it's working on Android

What does it show when you load the same page on a PC running Chrome and which is logged in with your Google account? Second, in your Chrome for Android browser, are you able to click on "Added to Desktop"? Does it do anything?

Chrome for Android does not support browser extensions.
There is an informational pop-up when accessing the Chrome Web Store homepage from mobile.

This means that the extension was remotely installed on Chrome Desktop (computer) instead, thus the text "Added to Desktop."
However, the Chrome Web Store does not support remote uninstallation (similar to Play Store Web), thus the extension can only be uninstalled from the computer.

I am not logged in with any account in chrome on my PC. I installed and removed this extension from chrome on my PC. But it is still showing in my Android.

Maybe log in from your PC with the same credentials you use on your Android. then try to desinstall it.
